# Input objects not shared across html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jsPsych in behavioral research. The developer of that library is very helpful, yet also busy, so I wanted to try and see if the stack overflow community could help me out with a more general js problem :)
In the instance where I'm getting issues, I push objects into an empty array to update the site after input. In this particular case, I use a script that allows me to use external html pages. My problem is, that, while this function here works in order to correctly display a java prompt when assessing a checkbox

```
var check_consent = function(elem) {
    if ($('#consent_checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("If you wish to participate, you must check the box next to the statement 'I agree to participate in this study.'");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
};
```

this here doesn't work in order to assess a text box

```
var inp = $("#ctry_box").val();
var check_sociodemo = function(elem) {
    if ($.trim(inp).length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please fill out the form.");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
};
```

More specifically, the prompt does actually work, but no matter what you type into "ctry_box", you can't continue the page and the prompt is shown no matter what the input.

Further, the developer set "data" as a object property designed to store data in accordance with individual variable choices. Regarding the same html files, I would like to gather the input from another text box like this

```
var sociodemo_block = {
    type: 'html',
    pages: [{url: "text/sociodemo.html", cont_btn: "end", check_fn: check_sociodemo}],
    data: [{age: age_box.value}],
    force_refresh: true
```

If I run this, the console tells me that age_box is not defined. Yet again, #consent_checkbox did work. Am I missing something fundamentally here or are the variables simply not shared across the files properly?
I'm very thankful for any help!

Comment: You should check `#ctry_box` value INSIDE `check_sociodemo` function. Regarding `age_box`, what element are you expecting it to target? Share relevant HTML markup too

Comment: True, I should've added that. age_box is just an input text box I use for people to give their age.

`<input type="text" min = "10" max = "99" maxlength = "2" id = "age_box" onkeypress = "return AllowNumbersOnly(event)"/>`